# Shiny: How to merge and abbreviate inputs to extract data from excel sheet?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set up an entry mask for users to enter distinct inputs in two fields that in turn extract data from an external excel sheet. The two input fields are **Geography** and **World Region**. There are several options to pick from for both fields, i.e. Africa or United States for Geography. The user can add as many input rows as he would like. The excel sheet that runs in the background has multiple columns, one for each possible combination of inputs that the user can select. Each column is named as a combined character string of the two abbreviations of the possible input options and has data in it that should be extracted and used later on.

Once the user has submitted their data, the string of characters made up of the two abbreviations should be produced for each input row so that it can be used to extract the data out of the respective column in the excel sheet. E.g if in the first input row the user has selected "Africa" and "Region1" the data of the column "Afr_Em" should be used. This should happen for each row of input the user indicates.

Right now, I am trying to store the abbreviations of the two fields in `InputList` to use this later to extract the data but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code so far:

```
# library(packages,etc.)

GeographyList <- c("Africa"="Afr",
                   "Asia"="AS",
                   "Europe"="EU")
WorldRegionList <- c("Region1"="Em",
                     "Region2"="Dev")

ui <- fluidPage(#....design etc.,

  # this is just a demo to show the input values
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

    actionButton('number', 
                 'Add row'),
    actionButton('delete_number', 
                 'Delete row'),
    actionButton("update", "Update View"),

    h4("allocation"),
    plotOutput("allocation"),
    textOutput("labels"))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  # (For remove button) Reactive value that is triggered by add and remove button
  reac <- reactiveValues()


  observeEvent(c(input$number,input$delete_number), {
    # you need to add 1 to not start with 0
    add <- input$number+1
    # restriction for delete_number > number
    delete <- if(input$delete_number > input$number) add else input$delete_number
    calc <- add - delete
    reac$calc <- if(calc > 0) 1:calc else 1
  })
  # Get new input by clicking Add Row
  observe({
    req(reac$calc)
    output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
      input_list <- lapply(reac$calc, function(i) {
        Geography <- input[[paste0("Geography",i)]]
        Region <- input[[paste0("WorldRegion",i)]]
        amount <- input[[paste0("amount",i)]]

        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                             label = paste0("Geography", i),
                             choices = GeographyList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Geography)) Geography)
          ),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(paste0("WorldRegion", i),
                             label = paste0("World Region", i),
                             choices = WorldRegionList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Region)) Region)),
          column(3, 
                 # Input: Specify the amount ----
                 numericInput(
                   paste0("amount",i),
                   label="Amount",
                   value = if(!is.null(amount)) amount else 0
                 )
          )
        )
      })
      do.call(tagList, input_list)
    })
  })

  # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row
  InputList <- eventReactive(input$update,{
    lapply(1:input$number, function(i) {
      paste0(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),"_",eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))))
    })})
  output$labels <- renderText({ paste0(InputList()) })

  # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row



  allocation <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    x <- c(input$amount1, input$amount2, input$amount3)
    lbls <- c(paste0(InputList()))
    pie(x, labels = lbls)
  })
  output$allocation <- renderPlot({
    if (input$update == 0)
      return()

    (allocation())
  })

}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and this is basically how the excel sheet looks like (at least partly, adding all possible combinations of abbreviations would be too much but I hope you understand the structure):

```
Afr_EM  Afr_EM  Afr_EM ...  LAC_Dev
5       5       3      ...  7
3       1       2      ...  8
...
```

As I am very new to shiny, I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: In your code above you have 2 `eventReactive`s waiting for `input$update` but it doesn't get created anywhere?

Comment: @Eli Berkow Oh sorry, I had an action button to "run" the input called input$update. I put it back in, hope it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out with the help of @Eli Berkow.
When including an action button to delete rows, I need to replace `input$number` in the `InputList` function with `tail(reac$calc, n=1)` to fetch the number of rows used.

Here is my full code:

```
# library(packages,etc.)

GeographyList <- c("Africa"="Afr",
                   "Asia"="AS",
                   "Europe"="EU")
WorldRegionList <- c("Region1"="Em",
                     "Region2"="Dev")

ui <- fluidPage(#....design etc.,

  # this is just a demo to show the input values
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

    actionButton('number', 
                 'Add row'),
    actionButton('delete_number', 
                 'Delete row'),
    actionButton("update", "Update View"),

    h4("allocation"),
    plotOutput("allocation"),
    textOutput("labels"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # (For remove button) Reactive value that is triggered by add and remove button
  reac <- reactiveValues()


  observeEvent(c(input$number,input$delete_number), {
    # you need to add 1 to not start with 0
    add <- input$number+1
    # restriction for delete_number > number
    delete <- if(input$delete_number > input$number) add else input$delete_number
    calc <- add - delete
    reac$calc <- if(calc > 0) 1:calc else 1
  })
  # Get new input by clicking Add Row
  observe({
    req(reac$calc)
    output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
      input_list <- lapply(reac$calc, function(i) {
        Geography <- input[[paste0("Geography",i)]]
        Region <- input[[paste0("WorldRegion",i)]]
        amount <- input[[paste0("amount",i)]]

        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                             label = paste0("Geography", i),
                             choices = GeographyList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Geography)) Geography)
          ),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(paste0("WorldRegion", i),
                             label = paste0("World Region", i),
                             choices = WorldRegionList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Region)) Region)),
          column(3, 
                 # Input: Specify the amount ----
                 numericInput(
                   paste0("amount",i),
                   label="Amount",
                   value = if(!is.null(amount)) amount else 0
                 )
          )
        )
      })
      do.call(tagList, input_list)
    })
  })

  # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row
  InputList <- eventReactive(input$update,{
    lapply(1:tail(reac$calc, n=1), function(i) {
      paste0(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),"_",eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))))
    })})
  output$labels <- renderText({ paste0(InputList()) })

  # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row



  allocation <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    x <- c(input$amount1, input$amount2, input$amount3)
    lbls <- c(paste0(InputList()))
    pie(x, labels = lbls)
  })
  output$allocation <- renderPlot({
    if (input$update == 0)
      return()

    (allocation())
  })

}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please test the below:

```
GeographyList <-list("Africa"="Afr",
                     "Asia"="AS",
                     "Europe"="EU")

WorldRegionList <- list("Region1"="Em",
                        "Region2"="Dev")

ui <- fluidPage(#....design etc.,

    # this is just a demo to show the input values
    mainPanel(
        uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

        actionButton('number', 
                     'Add row'),
        # Input: Click to run input
        actionButton("update", "Run")))

server <- function(input, output) {

    # By clicking the actionButton an additional row appears
    observeEvent(input$number, {
        output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
            input_list <- lapply(1:input$number, function(i) {

                fluidRow(
                    column(2,
                           selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                                       label = paste0("Geography", i),
                                       choices = GeographyList,
                                       multiple = FALSE,
                                       selected = NA)
                    ),
                    column(3,
                           selectInput(paste0("WorldRegion", i),
                                       label = paste0("World Region", i),
                                       choices = WorldRegionList,
                                       multiple = FALSE,
                                       selected = NA)
                    ))
            })
            do.call(tagList, input_list)
        })


    })

    # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row
    InputList <- eventReactive(input$update,{
        lapply(1:input$number, function(i) {
            paste0(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),"_",eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))))
        })})
}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have created the 2 lists at the beginning as actual named lists. This removes the need for your `switch` see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html) by *choices*. I don't have the full code but it seems to be working from what I can see.

Comment: Thank you! However, when I try to display the character strings for each row only that of the first input row shows up but not the rest. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I have no access to that piece of code unfortunately. You'll either need to edit your question or post a new one including that display part

Comment: I have update my code. The problem seems to be that I have another button that removes rows if needed - but I can't find the exact problem!